# Tomcat 8 cache issue - unable to remove cache completely

Tags: java, tomcat, queue, tomcat8, catalina

I have deployed a Java application running on tomcat 8 which is using a Queue,because of some previous errors the queue got stuck on the last element, I cannot remove the old queue elements even after deleteing the cache in Catalina/localhost/appname in var/lib/tomcat8/work/catalina/localhost/appname and var/cache/tomcat8/catalina/localhost/appname

How do I completely remove any traces of this queue elements before deploying the new version?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't come with any queuing system.  What are you using for the queue?

Comment: I'm using the java.util.queue library.

Comment: That doesn't persist anywhere - it's all in memory.  A Tomcat restart will reset everything.  Can you add any details? - I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Sure,So im using the java,util.queue to have a Queing mechanism in place which holds a list of files, upon processing one file, it is removed from the Queue. Because of a corrupt file the queue was stuck on that file and I deployed a fixed code of the app which can handle this. Even after restarting, deploying the new code the Queue is still stuck on that file, even though the file has been processed. I suspect tomcat is caching this somewhere, but not sure where.

Comment: Tomcat does maintain some data in it's `temp` directory.  I would take a look there too.  In your environment this would be in, I believe `/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp` though that may be wrong.  Or reboot - `/tmp` should be cleaned out after a reboot.